# Feature selection on datasets with both categorical and numerical features

Tags: dataset, feature-selection, categorical-data, numerical

I'm proposing a novel methodology for feature selection in the context of tabular datasets that contain both numerical and categorical features. In order to prove the efficacy of my methodology, I need datasets that have been previously used as benchmark for other feature selection methodologies. Can you suggest me datasets of this type or papers that show a result of a certain feature selection method on a particular public dataset?